# Cannot activate a sheet from a standalone script (Google Apps script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

In order to protect the code (so people can't see it) I manage my Spreadsheet from a standalone script.

All functions work besides activating the sheet or cell (these functions work withing bound script, the calculations are correct, a cell gets activated).

I tried to activate the sheet from standalone script and then added it as a library and called from bound script of my file. None works.

I need to activate the sheet and the cell on spreadsheet opening.

Here's my code (bound to spreadsheet):

```js
function onOpen() {      
    RandomNetwork.goToLastBlock()
}
```

Here's the code from a library (standalone script):

```js
//goes to the last block on the sheet
function goToLastBlock() {  

    var file = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1kTOcxVv7RgIvp-BVvbZyBbeE92HiAKm8hbFURh19Enc")

    var sheets = file.getSheets()

    for (var i in sheets) {

        var sheetID = sheets[i].getSheetId()

        if (sheetID === 908402362) {

            var lr = sheets[i].getLastRow()
            var cell = sheets[i].getRange(lr, 1)

            sheets[i].activate()
            sheets[i].setCurrentCell(cell)

            return
        }
    }
  }
```

When I run it from the bound script it finds this spreadsheet and the sheet, calculates the last row correctly. But when I run from the script it doesn't do anything.

**How can I activate the sheet and the cell from a standalone script**? I'll appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Ppl can easily get your library code from the bound script: `Logger.log(RandomNetwork.goToLastBlock)`

Comment: Stack Snippets should be used only for executable HTML/CSS/JavaScript code. In very rarely case it could be use on Google Apps Script client-side code but "never" with server-side code (you should create an api to your server side code for that which is something too convuluted for most of the Google Apps Script questions.

Comment: @TheMaster wow. What's the solution for security?

Comment: Sorry @Ruben didn't get what you've said)

Comment: It's true, that a library does not secure your code.  That can only be done by publishing an add-on, and having the user install the add-on.

Comment: @kiki What exactly is your security issue? Do you need to prevent people from seeing the code or do you need to prevent them from modifying the code? If you don't want people to see the code, is there a particular reason? Most "secrets" can be hidden by using the [properties service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties).

Comment: kiki Agree with @Alan  for code security.

Comment: Thank you guys. Prevent from seeing (a client asks for that). I use Properties service, how do you think it can prevent from seeing the code? I need to learn how to publish an addon too)

Answer (score 1):

Every time that you change the code in the library, you need to publish a new version, and you must also change the version number in the bound script for the library.

As a test, I put the following code in a stand alone script:

```
//goes to the last block on the sheet
function goToLastBlock() {  

    var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

    var sheets = file.getSheets()
    var theSheet = sheets[0];

    var lr = theSheet.getLastRow()
    var cell = theSheet.getRange(lr, 1)

    theSheet.activate()
    theSheet.setCurrentCell(cell)

    return theSheet.getSheetName();
}
```

Then, from a script bound to the sheet, I added the library (stand alone) to the bound script and ran the code from the bound script:

```
function onOpen() {      
    RandomNetwork.goToLastBlock()
}
```

The code activated the column A cell in the last row.

I published the library as a Web App to execute as "User Accessing the Web App" and "anyone within the organization"

It worked for me with the sample code provided and setting it up as described.

Comment: Don't forget about the libraries developer mode :)

Comment: Guys, I was in developer mode initially. Then I created a new version of a library, also published as a web app and still cannot get the library to work. Something wrong in connecting the library. Also webapp requres doGet() function, I feel like I don't need a web app here. What do you think?

Comment: Right now the developers mode on for both scripts projects, version 2 for both, I can choose the library and all functions are being suggested but not executed.

Comment: A `doGet()` simple trigger function is only needed if you are making an HTTPS GET request to the published URL.  `doGet()` is usually for rendering HTML to the browser, but it can also be used to get a response back without displaying HTML to the browser.  The point is, that you don't need a `doGet()` function to publish a script as a Web App.  If you want version control, then you need a way to create different versions.  And you can't do that without publishing.

Comment: That's confusing. `doGet()` is not needed and neither is publishing. You only need to create a [version](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/versions) and grant the users view access to the library code. If you want the end users to also use development mode, then the end users need to be [granted write access](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#testing_and_debugging_your_library). Either way, for your current testing purposes, neither of these seem to be issues.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot activate the sheet and cell from a standalone script.

Only container-bound scripts can make sheets & ranges active. The particular methods you're using are not explicitly mentioned in the [container-bound description](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound), but that's the reality.

Libraries have more nuanced scoping, which you can read more about [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#resource_scoping). As indicated in the table (in the link), libraries get access to the container. Essentially, because your container-bound script uses the library, the standalone script is copied–if you will–into the container-bound script and therefore gets access to those privileged methods.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I see that I can't set active ranges from a standalone script. And from library too? Is there any workaround? Anyone knows, guys?

Comment: @kiki You can from the library, but only if you execute the library code from within the container-bound script.

Comment: That's what I do in my example - run the library function from bound script: function onOpen() { randomNetwork.goToLastBlock() } randomNetwork is the library. Or you mean something else?

Comment: @kiki You wrote in your original post, "When I run it from library it finds this spreadsheet and the sheet, calculates the last row correctly." I understand that to mean that it *is* working, so I'm not sure what you're doing that isn't working.

Comment: I made a mistake. It works from the bound sheet. But not from the library with this code. Can you please help?

Comment: @kiki When you say that it doesn't work from the library, how are you executing the code? Are you clicking "run" in the library? That will not and will never work. You can *only* make this work if it is run in the bound script.

Comment: @kiki You wrote in your previous comment, "It works from the bound sheet. But not from the library with this code." I think you should take a moment to do some research, read what has been written by various people here, try some things and then, if necessary, come back with a clear question and a problem that can be reproduced.

Comment: I figured: the library is now working with me perfectly. Works everything besides activation of a sheet and a cell! So I think activation doesn't work whether from standalone script or when you run it from bound script as a library.